# Can you save an edited HTML in the inspect element, to the browser?

Tags: html, css, web-development-server

Can you save an edited HTML in the inspect element, to the browser? After I hit refresh, the web page goes looking back to normal and I want to keep it edited on my browser only for life.

Comment: don't refresh the browser till u have the styles copied

Answer (score 0):

You could press CTRL+S to save the page itself. But I suppose that is not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a html from a page on the web you cannot. The only other solution (and I use it sometimes) is to create a local Chrome / Firefox extension that alters the DOM via Javascript.

If it's a html present on your disk you can do it with DevTools on Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like save un html code on notepad and save it as html or edit html code from inspect but those solutions will make static web page and there is no way to make it dynamic only if you change the source code of web page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).